# Encrypt and or Decrypt multiple PDFs with the same password

Tags: shell-script

I would just want a simple way to encrypt multiple PDFs with the same Password.
Also do it from the CLI or terminal interface. A GUI would also be helpful.
I would like to do this in qpdf, because the encryption goes higher than 128. 
256 is good enough. I mean could it go higher like 512 or 1024? Any info would be helpful.

Comment: Check `pdftk` utility

Comment: Well, pdftk and qpdf are mostly the same. I'm talking about a script of some sorts so that I can password multiple PDFs at the same time. Even files with named spaces in them. I will do some more research and testing . Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set a owner or a user password using `pdftk`:

```bsh
for i in *;do pdftk "$i" output "out$i" owner_pw yourpw user_pw yourpw encrypt_128bit;done
```

Comment: Hell. this part "owner_pw yourpw user_pw yourpw encrypt_128bit"  is confusing, can you clarify please?

Comment: @Jagosix The first `yourpw` is the owner password you want to set and the second `yourpw` is the user passowrd that you want to use. If you do not know the differences between pdf user and owner password you can look it up [here](https://www.isunshare.com/pdf-password/pdf-owner-and-user-password-keep-pdf-safe.html). And the `encrypt_128bit` specifies that the file should be 128 bit encrypted instead of 40 bit. Those two are the only options, you can not go any higher than 128 as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have found a solution and tested it thoroughly. It works great in Linux.

I created a small script and named it `pwdalotofpdfs.sh` Lol. It asks for the user and owner password then it encrypts all of the pdfs within the current folder without bothering the original files. Also the files are encrypted at 256bits. The program I used is `qpdf`.

```
#!/bin/sh
clear

read -p "Input USER Password : " usrpwd
read -p "Input OWNER Password : " ownerpwd
 
for file in *.pdf
do
  qpdf --encrypt $usrpwd $ownerpwd 256 -- "$file" "${file%*.pdf}_pwd.pdf"
done

clear

echo "Files are completed"
```